# How can i geht the lenght of all data-attributes of an specific elements?

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute, string-length

HTML:

```
<div id="me" data-property-1="1" data-property-2="2" data-property-3="3"></div>
```

Is it possible to get the lenght of all data-attributes of the div with vanilla.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```js
const dataSetLength = Object.keys(document.getElementById('me').dataset).length;
console.log('Length of dataset:', dataSetLength);
```

```html
<div id="me" data-property-1="1" data-property-2="2" data-property-3="3"></div>
```